# Flutter: Send data back to specific list item

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to send data to a specific list item on the screen.

The logic is that you click on the specific card in the list it opens a second screen with an input field (see images below). You then submit your input and it changes the value of that specific card on the first screen.

What is the best way to achieve this?

[image] [image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

Instead of only pushing to another page, await for a return

```
final data = await Navigator.push(context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => InputScreen()));

setState(()
   myList.add(data); //do whatever you want with the return here
});
```

And in your InputScreen you do this:

```
Navigator.of(context).pop(data);
```

Also, if your user press the back button of their phone, it will return null, so you will need to handle that.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by doing the steps below:

1) In the `onTap` function of the card, await the result by adding the code below:

```
                     // on tap function of your card
   onTap: () async {
   // navigate to the second screen and wait for input user enters
         final result = await Navigator.push(context
                     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()));

         // call setstate to see your changes 
         setState(() {
         // add the input to your list
         myList.add(result);
          );
        },
```

1) In the onTap function of your submit button send back the result by adding the code below:

```
 // ontap function of your submit button
 onTap: () {
       // value is what the user has inputted in the text field
       Navigator.pop(context, value);
 },
```

Comment: hey Void, by any chance you know how to tackle this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67705273/build-data-back-to-listview-builder-flutter